# Why I cannot get public IP address?

Tags: azure

I am learning, I follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/automate-azure-tasks-with-powershell/6-exercise-create-resource-interactively

.I used

```
Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName learn-99f13ddd-a484-4120-b3fe-547fc77b9a7e -Name "testvm-eus-01"
```

[image]

Why I cannot get public IP address?